# Convert unix timestamp to readable date using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, unix

I have a sql database with unix timestamps.

(timestamp in db:`1388901215`)

I used the following to display get the timestamp from the db in php:

```
$timestamp=$row[created];
$created = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $timestamp);
echo $created;
```

This was the ouput:

> 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

Which I know is incorrect. I can't see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: echo out $timestamp befor conversion, please.

Answer (score 2):

You can also let MySQL do the job:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(your_column) FROM your_table;
```

Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function.

```
$timestamp=$row[created];
$created = date("Y-m-d\H:i:s", $timestamp);
echo $created;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`gmdate()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)

```
<?php
$timestamp=1388901215;
echo gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $timestamp); //"prints" 2014-01-05T05:53:35Z
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1388901215);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$timestamp=$row['created'];

$created = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $timestamp);
echo $created;
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT STR_TO_DATE(NOW()','%d-%b-%y %h.%i.%s')